# Excel 2013 : Conditional Formatting consecutive Duplicate in 1 column

Tags: excel, duplicates, excel-2013, conditional-formatting

I'm using Excel 2013 and I have a column with 30,000 items. Below is sample format of items , now using Conditional Formatting I wanted to highlight only consecutive columns where count > 2. I tried Conditional Formatting->Highlight Cells Rules ->Duplicate Values. It highlights all occurrences. 
I Only want to highlight **consecutive duplicate** columns? . 

Current requirement is not to use any additional columns but use existing column only.

ITEM 1
ITEM 2
**ITEM 3

ITEM 3**

ITEM 4
ITEM 5
ITEM 3
ITEM 2
**ITEM 4

ITEM 4**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve:

[image]

Apply the *Formula Is* option to cell **A1** with the formula:

```
=A1=A2
```

[image]

Then to **A2** apply the *Formula Is* option with the formula:

=OR(A2=A1,A2=A3)

Then copy the formatting of **A2** down the column.

Comment: thanks so much for your quick reply. it worked as required!

Comment: [You can also see this post.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34706068/why-does-this-excel-formula-return-different-results-for-conditional-formatting)