# Why does this excel formula return different results for conditional formatting?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

Here is some demo data:

[image]

You can see the formula used in Column B returns TRUE for any consecutive duplicates, but when used as a CF condition on $A$1:$A$14 it returns different results?

Here is the CF setup:

[image]

Comment: (+1 on the question) In `B1` the formula refers to the cell to its left (when it refers to `A1`) but when the CF rule is in `A1` it is (sort of) setting up a circular reference (which seems to be okay in CF rules). I don't completely understand what is happening here but I think that it has something to do with that.

Comment: Yes my understanding too was that circular references are fine in CF rules... I'll keep playing around with it but for now it's got me stumped...

Comment: Yes, it does seem quite mysterious.

Comment: The problem is the `IFERROR` which will not work properly in conditional formatting. But shall `A1` really be `TRUE`? Why not simply `=INDIRECT("A"&ROW(A1)-1)=A1` or `=(A1048576=A1)` as condition?

Comment: @AxelRichter because that would work for every cell _except_ A1, which in this case should be included as part of the consecutive set. Which is why A1 should indeed be true.

Comment: @MacroMan: But how shall `A1` ever be `TRUE` since the first occurance is always `FALSE`? In other words why is `A7` then `FALSE`?

Comment: @AxelRichter I understand your point, but the logic should be that all instances within a group of consecutive duplicates should be highlighted - in which case A1 should also be highlighted as part of the group. Technically speaking you are correct as the first instace isn't a duplicate in itself, however in this scenario I want to include the first instance ***if*** it is proceeded by consecutive duplicates. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the condition shall be true if either the predecessor or the successor is the same value.

Within conditional formatting you can think about the row numbers as circular. So the predecessor of  `A1` is `A1048576` and also the successor of `A1048576` is `A1`.

The same is with the column numbers. After `XFD` follows `A`.

So your formula for the conditional formatting is:

```
=OR(A1048576=A1,A1=A2)
```

or

```
=AND(A1<>"",OR(A1048576=A1,A1=A2))
```

for excluding empty cells.

As sheet formula this will not work. There

```
=OR(IFERROR(INDIRECT("A"&ROW(A1)-1)=A1,FALSE),A1=A2)
```

is need.

Comment: `Within conditinal formatting you can think about the row numbers as circular.` <-- I think this is what I was after, although I didn't realise it at the time! Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 2):

This may also help you. It will work for whole column also.

```
=IF(A1="","",OR(A1=A2,A1=IFERROR(OFFSET(A1,-1,0),"")))
```

[image]

Comment: So the problem was not the `IFERROR` but the `INDIRECT("A"&ROW(A1)...)`. because `OFFSET` will work. But the `IF` is not necessary in conditional formatting. `=AND(A1<>"",OR(IFERROR(OFFSET(A1,-1,0)=A1,FALSE),A1=A2))` will also work.

Comment: I used `if()` to work the function for full column `A:A`. If you do not use `if()` then it will highlight all empty cells. Otherwise have to use `=AND(A1<>""` to handle empty cells **which you already mentioned in comment.**